# Problem when trying to set up lag on netgear switch

Tags: switch, netgear-prosafe

When I go in to the switching>lag area of the netgear web portal, I get this
[image]

it says that ports 22 23 and 24 are configured for the lag, but I only need ports 23 and 24. When I click to configure the lag it gives me this; [image]

And it says that port 21 is configured, and none of the ones that are shown as being configured are actually selected. When I set it to how I want it to be, it makes no difference. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Which platform and which version of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when you're going to your Lag Membership page, the page is calling your ch1 LAG.  It's bugs like these that make me less and less of a fan of Netgear equipment.  I'd give the switch a reboot and try again.  If you're still having issues, it could be completely GUI related.  Try the CLI if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has nothing to do with it, but what's up with Lag 1?  It has only one port, which makes for a pretty lonely aggregated link. I have found that the netgear web gui is often temperamental but usually trying to tell me something (I use a bunch of GS728s and similar). LAG has always worked for me on Netgear but I did run into an issue with port mirroring via the GUI almost exactly like this. Maybe try clearing all the ports out of both LAGs and setting up the ones you need from scratch?  Also, the firmware notes are often mentioning GUI fixes so if you aren't running the latest that should be a consideration.